# JavaScriptCore get API console.log messages

Tags: javascript, jquery, swift, javascriptcore

I have a simple web app that prints streaming data to the console.log. This works just fine in a web page.

I would like to print the log messages directly onto the Xcode console as they come across the stream without using a web view.

Prefer everything to be in Swift if possible but Objective-C solution is ok.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <title>Barchart Market Data API Example</title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="../dist/barchart-marketdata-api-1.0.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(function() {
            var onMarketUpdate = function(message) {
                if (message.type == "TRADE") {

                    var q = client.getMarketState().getQuote(message.symbol);
                    if (q)
                    console.log('Symbol: ' + q.symbol +
                            '\nLast:' + q.lastPrice +
                            '\nVolume:' + q.volume +
                            '\nTime:' + q.time);
                }
            };


            var client = new Barchart.RealtimeData.Connection();

            client.connect('qsws-us-e-01.aws.barchart.com', 'user', 'password');

            client.on('marketUpdate', onMarketUpdate, 'ESZ6');

        });
    </script>
    <body>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I have been able to load the script above (everything in the script text/javascript tag into a file called myLib.js) as well as the required libraries

```
    let fileLocation1 = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("jquery", ofType: "js")!

    let jsSource1 : String
    do {
        jsSource1 = try String(contentsOfFile: fileLocation1)
    } catch {
        jsSource1 = "Contents of JavaScript not loaded."
    }

    let fileLocation2 = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("barchart-marketdata-api", ofType: "js")!

    let jsSource2 : String
    do {
        jsSource2 = try String(contentsOfFile: fileLocation2)
    } catch {
        jsSource2 = "Contents of JavaScript not loaded."
    }

    let fileLocation3 = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("myLib", ofType: "js")!

    let jsSource3 : String
    do {
        jsSource3 = try String(contentsOfFile: fileLocation3)
    } catch {
        jsSource3 = "Contents of JavaScript not loaded."
    }

    let context = JSContext()
    context.evaluateScript(jsSource1)
    context.evaluateScript(jsSource2)
    context.evaluateScript(jsSource3)
```

I am not sure how to get the output from the console.log into the context as it is inside a Jquery anonymous function.

It really does not have to come from the console.log, I could just return the string to the mac/iOS app.

Comment: Not entirely sure if 'console.log' is writeable but you could override it capturing everything sent to it possibly. ES6 proxies may help?

Comment: the `$(function() {` is confusing me how do I call this object from within swift and get anything returned?

Comment: Also I do not think that myLib is getting the required scripts like Jquery and barchart-marketdata-api like it would on the web.

Comment: I broke down and created a web view to test on. So I am not really familiar with jQuery but that `$(function() {` statement is really causing problems. I can get calls to any normal JavaScript function as long as they are BEFORE any jQuery calls. If the function comes after the jQuery then I always get "undefined" returned from my JSContext and JSValue calls... ??